# Websocket (Ratchet/zeroMQ) with Apache proxy and SSL - on a Plesk server

Tags: apache, ssl, websocket, zeromq, ratchet

I'm trying to get a websocket/push-server to run with SSL and can't get it to work.
Here are some informations about what I'm using and what I've done so far:

- Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS‬ server with Plesk 17.8.11
- Apache version 2.4.18
- Ratchet and zmq extension installed
- autobahn.js for websocket connection
- PHP-FPM (7.2.19) served by Apache
- Firewall disabled for testing
- Apache mods enabled: proxy, proxy_balacer, proxy_fcgi, proxy_http, proxy_wstunnel

When I use an non-SSL connection via autobahn.js to `ws://my.domain.net:8888/` everything works perfectly fine.
As soon as I try to use `wss://my.domain.net/wss/` I get 504 connection timeouts in my browser.

**Part of my push-server.php:**

```
$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
$pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->bind('tcp://0.0.0.0:5555'); // set to 0.0.0.0 for testing, was 127.0.0.1 before but didn't work either
$pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onMessage'));

$webSock = new React\Socket\Server('0.0.0.0:8888', $loop);
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
            new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                $pusher
            )
        )
    ),
    $webSock
);

$loop->run();
```

**The server is listening on both ports:**

```
php        3957               root   17u     IPv4          823972456      0t0       TCP *:8888 (LISTEN)
ZMQbg/0    3957  3958         root   17u     IPv4          823972456      0t0       TCP *:8888 (LISTEN)
ZMQbg/1    3957  3959         root   17u     IPv4          823972456      0t0       TCP *:8888 (LISTEN)


php        3957                  root   16u     IPv4          823972455      0t0       TCP *:5555 (LISTEN)
ZMQbg/0    3957  3958            root   16u     IPv4          823972455      0t0       TCP *:5555 (LISTEN)
ZMQbg/1    3957  3959            root   16u     IPv4          823972455      0t0       TCP *:5555 (LISTEN)
```

**My apache config:**

```
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyRequests Off
SetEnv proxy-initial-not-pooled 1
ProxyPass /wss/ https://my.domain.net:8888/
ProxyPassReverse /wss/ https://my.domain.net:8888/
```

I also tried to use

```
ProxyPass /wss/ wss://my.domain.net:8888/
```

but then I get the following error message

```
[proxy:warn] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /wss/. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

Now when I try to open a connection with autobahn.js to `wss://my.domain.net/wss/` the request loads for a while and ends in a 504 Gateway Time-out and I get the following error message:

```
[proxy_http:error] (103)Software caused connection abort: [client x.x.x.x:33362] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server my.domain.net:8888
[proxy:error] [client x.x.x.x:33362] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /wss/
```

**Part of the Request Headers:**

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key: WG/ajAsTaVhBgEeEz5wiUg==
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: wamp
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket
```

**Part of the Response Headers:**

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 578
Content-Type: text/html
Server: nginx
```

Opening the https://my.domain.net/wss/ in a browser ends in an Gateway Time-out as well, served by nginx.

I've spent like 2 days already googling and trying different solutions but nothing seems to work.
If you need more information, please let me know.
**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: did you find any solution?